# Place image on top of another image using bootstrap

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I have a multiplayer html game (not using canvas) where you have a portrait of your character and a portrait of the character you are playing against. I want to put an image over your opponents character image if they haven't yet loaded their page. The image will say "Not Ready" and when they are ready I'll remove this image.

I'm using bootstrap for positioning of everything though and the answers I've seen before have talked about absolute positioning. How can I position this "Not Ready" image on top of the character portrait displayed with the below code?

My display of character portraits is:

```
    <!--Portraits-->
    <div id="divPortraitRow" class="row" style="margin-bottom: 10px;">
        <div id="divPlayer" class="col-md-6 text-center">
            <img src="@Model.Player.Icon" />
        </div>

        <div id="divOpponent" class="col-md-6 text-center">
            <img src="@Model.Opponent.Icon" />
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If im not mistaken the character portrait image is `<img src="@Model.Player.Icon" />`? Then you would want to include the new placeholder image along side your current image (and inside of `<div id="divPlayer" class="col-md-6 text-center">`) like so:

```
 <div id="divPlayer" class="col-md-6 text-center">
   <img src="@Model.Player.Icon" />
   <img src="NEW IMAGE" /> <----new image here (order is not important)
 </div>
```

The new image would be set to `position: absolute` and the parent: `<div id="divPlayer" class="col-md-6 text-center">` needs to be set to `position: relative` otherwise the `absolute` image becomes relative to the body.

[**EXAMPLE FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/801fc84v/)

Comment: Didn't seem to work. The "not ready" image is to the right of the character portrait. The container div is inside another div defined as (<div class="container-fluid">) does that matter?

Comment: @user441521 look at the fiddle I included

Comment: So this is the problem I was hinting at with using absolute positioning. I'm using bootstrap to position things so by using absolute positioning with anything I lose the fluidness of that thing bootstrap. So depending on the page width the absolute values don't work right.

Comment: the only other way to put an image on top of an image with out absolute positioning it is by setting one of the images as a `background-image` on its parent.